# Is a bat file an application?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get my head around a DLL load library problem. The Windows Dynamic-Link Library Search Order is supposed to be

```
Memory
Known DLL's
Application Directory
System Directory
...etc,
```

as discussed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order and at many other places.

When I run a Windows Executable (Desktop Application) from a Batch file, does it inherit the 'application' folder from the Batch File?  (Because I'm running out of other explanations)

Comment: A batch file is not an application.  Cmd.exe, the program that interprets a batch file is.  Yes, a program you start from a batch file inherits the environment of Cmd.exe.  If you use SET in the batch file to change variables then the started program will see those as well, including PATH.  Poorly behaving programs often require that you start them with the default working directory set to a location they expect, use CD.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't consider a batch file an application at all.
It's more like a script, as it needs to be run through an actual application/executable program (like the DOS runtime, or CMD on Windows)

You can setup environment variables much like in old DOS times (if you need to define a Paths variable) through sysdm.cpl, but I'm not sure that would help for DLL searching